# Audio player with multiple track playing support

Tags: linux, audio, media-player

I am looking for an audio player which can play multiple audio files simultaneously (not in queue or playlist). Each audio track should have its own controls.

One example of such an application is [myNoise.net](http://mynoise.net/). I'm looking for such a player for Ubuntu or Linux.
I have tried [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), but it doesn't have a volume control for each track.

Comment: Are you looking to play 2 or more than 2 tracks at any one time?

Comment: more than 2 and at least 10

Comment: @SteveBarnes if you can recommend a player for 2 track, plz mention it

Comment: What about command-line programs like `mpv`?

Comment: @wb9688 If that can be used suitably, sure! Please add an answer with some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For controlling 2 tracks at a time with independent volume controls you could use the cross mix facility of a VirtualDJ such as [Mixxx](http://www.mixxx.org/) which allows:

- Independent control of the volume of each track,
- Changing the proportion of the overall volume between the two tracks,
- Timeshifting tracks for beat sync
- Time stretching/Tempo Shift tracks to sync
- Curve based cross fade
- Plays MP3, M4A/AAC, Ogg Vorbis, FLAC, WAVE, and AIFF formats
- Free & Cross Platform, (**Linux**, Windows, OS-X).
- A lot more...
  [image: User IF]

Since the only reason that springs to mind for needing more than 2 tracks at once is for "sampling" it might be worth mentioning that in addition to having 2 tracks playing for cross fades/mixing you can have up to 4 "samples" loaded. [image: Sampler]

According to the [manual](http://www.mixxx.org/manual/latest/chapters/user_interface.html#the-sampler-section) each sampler deck can have a whole track loaded but with limited controls - including volume controls for that Sample - but I am not sure if you can have more than 1 sample playing at a time.

Comment: I was already using this one. Though A bit complex and limited. Thanks for your effort. But, still looking for better suggestion

Comment: You could always roll your own - if you are not looking for a lot of other facilities then http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/20/wxpython-creating-a-simple-mp3-player/ would be a good starting point - note that as the number of tracks grows the chances of disk contention - where different files need to read at once - will grow.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but since the OP wasn't satisfied with the only answer, which offered a DJ program, I'm going to suggest a DAW.

DAW stands for Digital Audio Workstation, which is a category of apps that can do pretty much anything you can think of with audio:

- Play oodles of tracks at once from individual files
- Accept multitrack live input
- Run the provided audio through effects, mixing busses, etc.
- Send the results to any number of live outputs or files

It's basically all the electronic processing equipment in one box that you'd need to produce a CD, from initial recording to final mastering.  Just add mics, room treatment, and some studio speakers.

---

My favorite is [Ardour](http://ardour.org/), mostly because it's free and can do everything that I've wanted to so far.  You can install it alongside everything else on your computer, or to use it extensively, you can get it preinstalled with [UbuntuStudio](http://ubuntustudio.org/), which itself installs just like regular Ubuntu.  I occasionally use it to remix some classic songs that I like: Smoke on the Water by Deep Purple, Sarajevo by TSO, etc.  The process goes something like:

1. Find a MIDI file that has some decent instrumentation, ignoring the exact sounds for the moment
2. Split the drum track of the MIDI file into one track per sound
3. Render each track to a separate WAV file using a software synthesizer that accepts SoundFonts (this is where I fix the sounds that I ignored before)
4. Set up Ardour to work like a software mixing console with per-channel and group effects, import the WAV files, turn up my speakers(*), and have fun!

(*) The speakers need to turn up for this because I'm going to produce a "live" mix instead of a mastered recording.  A mastered recording has a known peak level and so it can use all of the headroom provided by the storage medium and the system that's used to play it.  A live mix has less control of that peak level, so it needs to leave some headroom to accommodate that.  Thus, the speakers need to be set higher to produce the same volume as a mastered recording.

---

So that's one thing you can do with a DAW.  Here's another:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-YNIG-erAk

In that example, the presenter used a different DAW called [FL Studio](http://www.image-line.com/flstudio/) to

1. Load a bunch of short audio samples that he took from a movie as if they were recorded as such, some repeated or in sequence on the same track
2. Add some in-app synthesized sounds on their own tracks
3. Mix, master, and save that soundtrack to use in a separate video editor, where he realigned the movie clips with their corresponding audio samples.  (and muted the video clips of course)

The result is:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJjjDvbK_UE

---

Those are just a couple of things you can do with a DAW.  I don't know what your original purpose was, but maybe that'll get you started.

Comment: The original purpose was to re-create the same combination of sounds like that site. I don't know why SE didn't notify me about this answer. I'll definitely try the solution and give feedback to you.

Comment: I'm trying your solution right now. It's interesting. +1